# Redirect 301 not working with .html pages

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have one website which is now moved on new domain(Old domain is also active)
the old URL is like this:
http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/register.html

And the new URL is

http://newexample.com/index.html
http://newexample.com/register.html

Now I want to redirect the user from the old domain to the new domain

```
Redirect 301 / http://newexample.com/index.html
```

By adding the above code in the .htaccess file I can redirect the user, and it working also.

but when someone hit this `http://example.com/index.html` then it won't redirect

**Solutions I have tried so far is**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

this one also

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://example.com/index.html http://newexample.com/index.html
```

This one also

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://newexample.com/index.html
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

**The old URL is .html and the new URL also have .html**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to redirect old to new.  That you figured out and it works.  Then you want to redirect `http://newexample.com/index.html` to `http://newexample.com/index.html`?!?  They are the same, why redirect something to the same thing?  Please clarify...

Comment: @Nic3500 Ohh my bad, that's the mistake in adding questions updated.

Comment: Check this: https://www.lifewire.com/modrewrite-to-redirect-whole-site-3469104.  This you put in the VirtualHost for `http://example.com`.